# UICellView cell layout in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to use a UICollectionView to create a grid which a user can set to be x cells by y cells (entered in text boxes), while still occupying the same width on the screen.

I have been able to create a grid view which contains the correct number of cells, but these aren't in the correct layout yet, i.e. entering 5 by 7 will give 35 cells but not in a 5 cell by 7 cell layout. This is the code I have so far.

MyCollectionViewCell.swift
        import UIKit

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var cellLabel: UILabel!

}
```

CreateNewProject.swift

```
class CreateNewProject : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var widthTextBox: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var lengthTextBox: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var myCollection: UICollectionView!

    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard

    @IBAction func updateView(sender: AnyObject) {
        let widthValue = Int(widthTextBox.text!)
        let lengthValue = Int(lengthTextBox.text!)
        multiplyValue = Int(widthValue! * lengthValue!)
        createArray()
    }


    func createArray() {
        var i = 0
        while i < multiplyValue {
            items.append("")
            i += 1
        }
        myCollection.reloadData()
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(self.items.count)
    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        // Use the outlet in custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.cellLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        return cell
    }    
}
```

I have constrained the UICollectionView on the left, right and top and was hoping to programatically resize the cells in the collection view to be UICollectionView.width / x (the number of cells wide chosen by the user).

Not sure of the best way to do this, and also need to keep some white space between the individual cells. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, add an extension of your view controller that implements the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let  size = collectionView.frame.size.width / CGFloat(cols) - CGFloat((cols - 1)) * spacingBetweenCells
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    }
}
```

`spacingBetweenCells` represents here the spacing you want to place between your cells.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code to add to your collectionView.  The properties `cellsAcross`, `cellsDown`, `horizGap`, and `vertGap` are the values you can set in your app.  The `horizGap` and `vertGap` are set in the methods `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` and `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex`.  `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` will compute the necessary dimensions of your cell to make it work.

```
var cellsAcross = 5
var cellsDown = 7
var horizGap = 4
var vertGap = 4

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellsAcross * cellsDown
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(vertGap)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(horizGap)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Compute the dimensions of a cell for a cellsAcross x cellsDown layout.

    let dimH = (collectionView.bounds.width - (CGFloat(cellsAcross) - 1) * CGFloat(horizGap)) / CGFloat(cellsAcross)

    let dimV = (collectionView.bounds.height - (CGFloat(cellsDown) - 1) * CGFloat(vertGap)) / CGFloat(cellsDown)

    return CGSize(width: dimH, height: dimV)
}
```

---

[image: Simulator demonstration]

For this demo, I added the following code:

```
@IBAction func threeBy5(sender: UIButton) {
    cellsAcross = 3
    cellsDown = 5
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func fourBy6(sender: UIButton) {
    cellsAcross = 4
    cellsDown = 6
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func fiveBy7(sender: UIButton) {
    cellsAcross = 5
    cellsDown = 7
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

// Handle screen rotation
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let rows = 7
let columns = 3

let spaceBetweenRows = 2
let spaceBetweenColumns = 4

var cellHeight: CGFloat {
    get {
        return collectionView.frame.height/CGFloat(rows)-CGFloat(spaceBetweenRows)
    }
}

var cellWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return collectionView.frame.width/CGFloat(columns)-CGFloat(spaceBetweenColumns)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rows*columns
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(spaceBetweenRows)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(spaceBetweenRows)
}

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
}
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_38993378" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <collectionView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="StH-xe-9BK">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="600" height="580"/>
                            <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="ILL-QA-nex">
                                <size key="itemSize" width="50" height="50"/>
                                <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                            </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                            <cells>
                                <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="cell" id="NTl-75-34J">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                    <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                    </view>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                </collectionViewCell>
                            </cells>
                        </collectionView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="StH-xe-9BK" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="RD1-j0-nbz"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="StH-xe-9BK" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="SMe-NI-E7C"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="StH-xe-9BK" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wfy-db-euE" secondAttribute="top" id="hxb-pd-z2C"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="StH-xe-9BK" secondAttribute="trailing" id="zgF-i5-4fX"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="collectionView" destination="StH-xe-9BK" id="eU8-eE-LXc"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="706" y="586"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

**results on different iPhones**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2 version for the answer provided by @vacawama:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(vertGap)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(horizGap)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Compute the dimensions of a cell for a cellsAcross x cellsDown layout.

    let dimH = (collectionView.bounds.width - (CGFloat(cellsAcross) - 1) * CGFloat(horizGap)) / CGFloat(cellsAcross)

    let dimV = (collectionView.bounds.height - (CGFloat(cellsDown) - 1) * CGFloat(vertGap)) / CGFloat(cellsDown)

    return CGSize(width: dimH, height: dimV)
}
```