# How do I make a UICollectionView that always has 2 rows and 4 columns

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

My Goal:
[image]

What I want to do is have a UICollectionView that has 4 items stacked on top of 4 (a 2x4 table) at all times.

I've figured out how to populate the view with data, but I can't figure out how to keep the rowsXcolumns ration

If you think this question is a repeat, please comment first so I can clarify why its not, as there are similar questions to mine. (I assure you, mine is different)

I'm not sure if I need to add a UICollectionViewLayout or something, help if you can please.

Thanks! :D

Comment: yes, the picture is of html, I just made that to show the concept

Comment: Check out this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38994987/1630618

Comment: otherwise, i'll just close this question

Comment: I can link yours as a duplicate.  That will help others find the other answer.

Comment: ok, do i need to do anything for that?