# UICollectionView cell autosize

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autosize

I have a two issues for my CollectionViews, I am trying to create an Instagram clone and I would like to display 3 cells per row, thus changing the cell width depending on the screen width.

I have this code, which is more or less the answers I could find online, but it does not work.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

 let size = CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.size.width - 10) / 2, height: (self.view.frame.size.width - 10) / 2)

 return size
}
```

Do you have any idea on what to do? Maybe it is something I have to enable or I don't know.

Thank you,

N

Comment: Please provide you problem..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38994987/1630618

Answer (score 1):

You probably forget to inherit  `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, so recheck and do like below.

```
class MyViewControler: UIViewController ,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

 let size = CGSize(width: (self.collectionView.bounds.width)/3 - 10, height: (self.collectionView.bounds.width)/3 - 10)

 return size
}
```

and don't forget to confirm `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol