# Call UICollectionView protocol methods to change the amount of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on a Minesweeper game and I chose to use a UICollectionView for the grid of the game. I am trying to make it so the user can change the size of the board/grid. I have it all set up now all I need is to call the UICollectionView protocol methods like when it is set up initially. How can I do this?

These are the methods I implemented in ViewController.swift that I want to call again.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return board.squares.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // Get a SquareCollectionViewCell object
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SquareCell", for: indexPath) as! SquareCollectionViewCell

    // Get square that the collection view is trying to display
    let square = board.squares[indexPath.row]

    // Set that square for the cell
    cell.setSquare(square)

    // Make a border for the cell
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    return cell
}
```

I tried collectionView.reloadData() but that did not work for me. I hope this isn't a duplicate question or super obvious. Maybe there is a better way to do what I am trying to do, but I am still new and this is what I came up with.

EDIT:
Ok I have edited my code and it works now! Yay! My new problem is I have a second ViewController to change the size of the board (like a settings view), and when I try to apply the changes to the board from the second ViewController I get this error next to the first change of collectionView:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

So I guess when I am viewing a different ViewController collectionView is nil? Is there any easy fix for this?

Comment: where in the code you are calling reloadData? Also, show the code for changing the size of the board/grid.

Comment: you can manage amount using index tag in collection view cell.

Comment: Take a look at what I did here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38994987/1630618

Comment: the code for changing the size of the board is simply changing the number of total cells since thats how the board is made originally. I was calling reloadData in a function that updates all of the cells. actually i tried a few different places. I will try your solution when I work on this later @vacawama